# Targeting Button that changes from "Next" to "Submit" on Last Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code for my button...Is is the code give from FeulUX for their Wizard:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Submit">Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
```

I want to target the button only when it is on the last click (i.e. when it turns to submit). I have this as my code:

```
$('*[button.="Submit"]').click(function(){
        console.log('success');
    });
```

But it logs success after each button click (even if the button still reads Next).

How do I target the button only when it's text has changed to submit?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not create a new submit button? Some one can change the InnerText atribute /Type of button and have security/logic problems.

Comment: The code was create by FeulUX and was used in other things in my form. It would be easier to target what they have then modify their UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if using `button` as a selector is enough, from what we've seen above, but basically you just need an if statement in the event handler...

```
$("button").click(function() {
    if (this.innerText === "Submit" || $(this).data("last") === "Submit") {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

You can't assign the event to a button with the text "Submit" as that won't exist at the time.  You could use event delegation and assign the click handler to a parent element, but there's really no need if you can just do the above.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed, thank you! The button tag is in relation to the FeulUX Wizard UI and I am unable to add form submit or create a new button unless I risk breaking everything else my code.

Comment: DO NOT USE THE INNERTEXT. It will not allow to change the language of your app instead you insert a HARDCODE in your  IF statement. Please, check my response

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Whilst what you're saying is correct, there is no mention here of different languages, so that's not relevant.  There could be a million scenarios that would break any piece of code, so let's just stick to what we're presented with, and know :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter

```
$('button').
filter(function(){
  return ($(this).text()=='submit' || $(this).text()=='Submit')
  });
```

Attaching handler to it:

```
 $('button').
    filter(function(){
      return ($(this).text()=='submit' || $(this).text()=='Submit')
      })
  .click(function(){
    console.log('success')
  });
```

**See Demo:**

```js
$('button').
filter(function(){
  return ($(this).text()=='submit' || $(this).text()=='Submit')
  }).css({"color":"yellow"}).click(function(){
   alert("success");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Submit">Next</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went with the IF statement above as it seems simpler

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to check the button target PLEASE CHECK NOW THIS OPTION**

**EDIT** CHANGED TO RETRIEVE DATA-LAST (YOUR NEEDS) AND TO CONTROL, FOR EXAMPLE, WHEN PUSHING NEXT AND PREV, A MAXNUMBER IS CHECKED TO DETECT IF IT IS LAST PAGE, AND THEN IF IT´s LAST, SHOW MESSAGE

**EDIT** CONTROL TO HIDE CORRECTLY THE MESSAGE AND DELETE SUBMIT CONDITION ON PREV CLICK

```js
var lastmax = 3;
var last = 0;
var islast = false;

function gonext() {
  console.log(last);
  if (last < lastmax) {

    last += 1;
  }

  if (last == lastmax) {
    $(".message").css("display", "");
    $("button.btn-next").attr("data-last", "Submit");
  }

}

function goback() {

  if (last > 0) {

    last -= 1;
  }
  $(".message.last").css("display", "none");
      $("button.btn-next").attr("data-last", "");

}



$("button.btn-prev").click(function(obj, event) {

  goback();
});


$("button.btn-next").click(function(obj, event) {

  if ($(this).attr("data-last") === "Submit") {
    alert("SUBMITTED");
  } else {
    gonext();
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="message" > PLEASE, CLICK 4 TIMES</span>
<div class="actions">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Prev</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="">Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> 
  </button>
  <span class="message last" style="display:none"> YOU ARE IN THE LAST, NOW CLICK</span>
</div>
```

Please, check this to BETTER detect a form submit, not a click on a "submit" named button.

```js
$("form").submit(function(event) {

  alert('success, you´ve detected a form send');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="submit">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why -1 ??  please read again!!  The use of ther INNER TEXT of the button IS NOT A GOOD IDEA  if you have a differente languages app... +

Comment: thanks but I couldn't change the format of the button without breaking the rest of the UI on my page..I didn't vote it down so not sure.

Comment: the format??? you dont need to break the format. Check the answer carefully, Seconde snippet  refers just to button.target and runs the desired funcionality

Comment: I don't have a form tag in my code. Here is the entire div:

Comment: <div class="actions">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>Prev</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-next" data-last="Submit">Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

Comment: Anyway, where i wrote "target" you can write "data-last" and it will work the same way with data-last attribute. Then you will not change your data-model.

Comment: is that what you mean/need?

Comment: Just tried your first code snippet and it didn't work

Comment: oh okay let me try it

Comment: Just tried it (used console.log instead of alert) and it is logging "success" each time the button is clicked; regardless of if it says "Next" or "Submit"

Comment: thanks but it is still logging each button click and not just at the end (as I would like it to do)

Comment: I dont understand "at the end" you said 

"I want to target the button only when it is on the last click (i.e. when it turns to submit). " <--- it checks then the "data-last" === "submit" isn´t it?¿??¿?¿?¿ I could not understand what you mean.

Comment: maybe you wanna mean that "when clicking next, make the submit button active, or something like this?, then control the click on submit?"

Comment: @tiaNaturally did u tried the first snippet again? I did some changes, to show u the way u should work! hope it can solve your question!

Answer (score 0):

Just attach an event to the button like so:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    if($(this).data('last') === "submit")
    {
        console.log("success!");
    }

});
```